# How to get Photoshop to open with a transparent layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs4

Photoshop (CS4) always opens a new file with a white *Background* layer that I nearly always delete. Is it possible to get it to open with a non-locked transparent layer instead?

Comment: Which version of Photoshop do you use? I'd like to know this as well, but it would help the helpers if you specified. I use Photoshop CS5, and experience this behavior.

Comment: mewoshh's fix is the same for the last few versions of photoshop at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File -> New` or <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Then from the drop-down list `Background Contents` choose `Transparent`.